# C# Encryption Information

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, md5, sha

We are using below code to encrypt/decrypt text to store some sensitive information into our database.

```
public static string Encrypt(string inputText)
{
    const string ENCRYPTION_KEY = "MY_KEY";
    byte[] SALT = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY.Length.ToString());

    System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = null;
    byte[] plainText = null;
    System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = null;

    try
    {
        rijndaelCipher = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();
        plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputText);
        SecretKey = new System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT);

        using (System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16)))
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cryptoStream = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher = null;
        plainText = null;
        plainText = null;
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string inputText)
{
    string ENCRYPTION_KEY = "MY_KEY";
    byte[] SALT = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY.Length.ToString());

    System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = null;
    byte[] encryptedData = null;
    byte[] plainText = null;

    try
    {
        rijndaelCipher = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();
        encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
        System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT);

        using (System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(encryptedData))
            {
                using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cryptoStream = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
                    int decryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText, 0, decryptedCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
    finally
    {
        rijndaelCipher = null;
        encryptedData = null;
        plainText = null;
    }
}
```

I am not original developer who wrote this code, I need to write some documentation related to security so want to know the exact name of above algorithm. Can someone tell me what is the exact name of above methodology to encrypt/decrypt text. Like MD5, SHA256, AES etc.

I googled a lot but not able to find proper confident answer.

Thanks.

Comment: MD5 and SHA256 are not encryption algorithms. They are hashing algorithms. The difference is there is no way to "decrypt" a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rijndael is the algorithm that won AES competition, but only for the version with 128 bits of BlockSize. Microsoft doc states that the default value for `RijndaelManaged` class is 128 so this code uses `AES-256-CBC` with *PKCS7* padding (the key is 32 bytes and no mode is specified).

However this code is very unsecure: you should use a mode such as GCM, or CBC/CTR plus a checksum, and the key should never be derivated from a simple hardcoded ascii string, no matter how long or complex it is, with the salt being a simple copy of it. Finally the IV should be random and saved along the cipherText and not derivated from the key, otherwise attacks common for ECB mode could be applied here as well.

PS: `RijndaelManaged` is marked as obsolete and `Aes` or `AesCryptoServiceProvider` should be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and time. Can you please share some code snippets if possible for what you mentioned in your answer.